# How nodejs or express works in angular framework?

Tags: node.js, angular

Need to know about mean stack development. How the node.js connects with angular. I know the one method which is connect angular by rest apis. So it same in MEAN ? We make apis with node&Express and call in angular app ? OR there is some other options too ?

Comment: [ask]..........

Comment: Sorry ill try to follow the link next time :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Angular, I think you need to first understand the difference between and the separation of frontend and backend.

Your frontend Angular application is an SPA (Single Page Application), which makes calles to another application. This is your API, which is your backend application. This could either be a PHP script or a NodeJS script (which could use Express or any other library that helps you building a REST API).

Get started by looking at [how to build an Angular app](https://angular.io/start) and [how to build a REST API with NodeJS and Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html).

Comment: Ok so there is only one way to call data in our angular application which is api right ? It can be php or node

Comment: There are many ways to make a request to another source (eg. Axios or fetch), and PHP or NodeJS are two ways (of many 100's) to build a REST API.